# How to enable fingerprint to my own application in android

Tags: android

I am doing an application and thought of keeping fingerprint option for login into the app, I already included Username and password things, which is similar to discover app. Please let me know how to enable that option in android

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fingerprint API for android phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29006960/fingerprint-api-for-android-phone)

Answer (score 1):

First of all most of the Android devices doesn't have a fingerprint sensor. As far as I know Samsung has a wide range of devices that supports this feature. If you are interested about working on fingerprint feature for Samsung devices only, you can use the official **Samsung Pass SDK** which provides accessing the fingerprint sensor easily.

Here goes the official link,
http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy#pass

**What Is Pass SDK?**

Pass SDK allows you to use fingerprint recognition features in your application. With Pass SDK, you can provide reinforced security, since you can identify whether the current user actually is the authentic owner of the device.

Comment: Hi Thanks for that!! How to integrate the pass sdk and android. Actually I don't have any idea about pass sdk. Please let me know

Comment: Check the getting started page, It has a good documentation of starting and running a Pass SDK enabled project, http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000182