# Kivy - How to authenticate Kivy apps using fingerprint scanners

Tags: android, kivy, fingerprint, biometrics, android-fingerprint-api

I am hoping to make use of fingerprint scanners within my Kivy app for authentication.

Unfortunately, I haven't found any documentation regarding how to do this. I'm quite new to Kivy development, and I was hoping to achieve this by (e.g. for Android) importing the android API and calling the appropriate method. However after reading [this stackoverflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29279982/5179470) it appears:

> Fingerprint scanner is not a feature in Android. So each company as Samsung, Motorola, HTC create is own API and SDK to access to fingerprint sensor.

(e.g. [SamsungPass](http://developer.samsung.com/release-note/view.do?v=R000000009)).
Although I then found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30544898/5179470)

> Google has now announced a generic fingerprint API for Android that can be utilised by any custom apps for authorisation ...
>
> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
> ```

**Any help regarding how I can add fingerprint authentication to Kivy apps is greatly appreciated. Thanks**