# Android FingerPrint scanner match data with server saved fingerprints

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, fingerprint

I have android application and backend is .NET site.

I have already enrolled my users with FingerPrints using Hampster Fingkey Scanner and stored their finger prints in Server.

Is there any ways using I can get FingerPrint and send that data to server and match in my SQL DB from Android ?

is this possible ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Android's Fingerprint Scanner for Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276026/using-androids-fingerprint-scanner-for-application)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access the actual fingerprint. If you could, any malicious app with access to the fingerprint scanner could steal a very private piece of information (which could potentially be used for identity theft, let alone frame you for a crime you did not commit).

I know that this is Android and not iOS, but I still think it's relevant to read and think about [what Apple has to say about security and privacy for its Touch ID technology](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204587):

> Touch ID doesn't store any images of your fingerprint. It stores only
>   a mathematical representation of your fingerprint. It isn't possible
>   for someone to reverse engineer your actual fingerprint image from
>   this mathematical representation. The chip in your device also
>   includes an advanced security architecture called the Secure Enclave
>   which was developed to protect passcode and fingerprint data.
>   Fingerprint data is encrypted and protected with a key available only
>   to the Secure Enclave. Fingerprint data is used only by the Secure
>   Enclave to verify that your fingerprint matches the enrolled
>   fingerprint data. The Secure Enclave is walled off from the rest of
>   the chip and the rest of iOS. Therefore, iOS and other apps never
>   access your fingerprint data, it's never stored on Apple servers, and
>   it's never backed up to iCloud or anywhere else. Only Touch ID uses
>   it, and it can't be used to match against other fingerprint databases.

Do you really need to compare *actual* fingerprints? Wouldn't it be sufficient to compare a set of secrets guarded by the fingerprint scanners? If you can indeed just compare secrets guarded by the fingerprint scanners, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37115194/1214974) will probably guide you towards a solution.