# Pandocs in Android for File Reader/Editor App

Tags: android, editor, filereader, pandoc

I want to create reader/editor app. For that I came to know [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/index.html) is there which is basically universal document converter. So my question is how we can use pandoc in android as it is Haskell library for converting from one markup format to another, and a command-line tool that uses this library.

Is there any other tool available for reader/editor app which supports multi format type converter and reading/editing functionality in android app.

Comment: Do you want to run pandoc itself on Android? If so, you may be able to run it in environments like [Termux](https://termux.com/).

Comment: @kotatsuyaki No I want to use pandoc in my code as in backend process it will be used for converting files.

Comment: By saying "backend process", did you mean a backend server, or did you mean a child process on an Android device? If you have a backend server, just run the pandoc executable on it.

Comment: @kotatsuyaki Backend Process means Child process in android or you can say "Service" which will do things for me using pandoc.

Comment: @kotatsuyaki Can you please also let me know how I can run it using Termux?

Comment: (I'm not familiar with Android app dev) So you want to run some form of pandoc on Android devices themselves within your app. Since pandoc is [written as a Haskell library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc), one possible route would be to go Haskell <-> C <-> Java / Kotlin, while it definitely wouldn't be an easy task. Alternatively you may try [running pandoc as a bundled native binary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4703131/12122460).

Comment: The Termux app provides Linux environments, so if you know how to run pandoc on any Linux distribution, it's more or less the same on Termux.